# Incorrect sizeof() of template argument when inheriting from unordered_map in visual c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, visual-studio-2015, sizeof, unordered-map

When declaring a class template that inherits from `std::unordered_map`, I'm getting the wrong size of the template argument when running in Visual C++ 2015.

The code below works as expected on Ubuntu 64-bit, when compiled with

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
```

outputting the following:

```
OUTSIDE: sizeof(my_key_type) = 12, sizeof(my_value_type) = 24
INSIDE: sizeof(my_key_type) = 12, sizeof(my_value_type) = 24
INSIDE(WTF?): sizeof(key_type) = 12, sizeof(value_type) = 24
```

But in Visual C++ 2015 on a 64-bit machine, I'm getting:

```
OUTSIDE: sizeof(my_key_type) = 12, sizeof(my_value_type) = 24
INSIDE: sizeof(my_key_type) = 12, sizeof(my_value_type) = 24
INSIDE(WTF?): sizeof(key_type) = 12, sizeof(value_type) = 40
```

If I don't inherit from `std::unordered_map`, then everything works fine both on Ubuntu and in VC2015. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for your help - here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

class my_key_type {
    unsigned int _int1;
    unsigned int _int2;
    unsigned short _short1;
    unsigned short _short2;
public:
    bool operator == (const my_key_type &other_key) const {
        return (memcmp(this, &other_key, sizeof(my_key_type)) == 0);
    };
};

namespace std {
    template <> struct hash<my_key_type> {
        std::size_t operator()(const my_key_type &key) const {
            return std::hash<string>()(std::string((const char *)&key, sizeof(my_key_type)));
        };
    };
};

class my_value_type {
    bool _flag;
    unsigned long long _count1;
    unsigned long long _count2;
};

#define INHERITS_FROM_UNORDERED_MAP 1
#if (INHERITS_FROM_UNORDERED_MAP == 0)
template <typename key_type, typename value_type> class kv_map {
#else
template <typename key_type, typename value_type> class kv_map : public std::unordered_map<key_type, value_type> {
#endif
public:
    void test_print() {
        printf("INSIDE: sizeof(my_key_type) = %ld, sizeof(my_value_type) = %ld\n", sizeof(my_key_type), sizeof(my_value_type));
        printf("INSIDE(WTF?): sizeof(key_type) = %ld, sizeof(value_type) = %ld\n", sizeof(key_type), sizeof(value_type));
    };
};

int main() {
    printf("OUTSIDE: sizeof(my_key_type) = %ld, sizeof(my_value_type) = %ld\n", sizeof(my_key_type), sizeof(my_value_type));
    kv_map<my_key_type, my_value_type> map;
    map.test_print();
};
```

Comment: I would guess it has something to do with padding added by the compiler between the `bool` and the following `unsigned long long`. In addition, I would check the V-table pointer that is added to your class when inheriting from a (presumably) class which declares virtual functions. Different compilers might be using different implementations for that (although I doubt that this is the issue in this case).

Comment: [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) is not designed to be inherited from, it doesn't have a virtual destructor. Or rather it doesn't have *any* virtual functions, but it's the lack of virtual destructor that's going to bit you most in the behind. If you want to inherit part of the interface, then you could possibly use private inheritance.

Comment: To follow on from what Joachim says: Don't inherit from `std::unordered_map` - contain it.  (Use has-a, not is-a).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::unordered_map` has a type called `value_type`

```
value_type  std::pair<const Key, T>
```

It's almost certainly that you're picking that up - as that includes the key data as well.

Change the name of your templated type and see what happens.

Comment: @MartinBonner Whenever VS disagrees, always suspect VS.   They are self admittedly not even C++11-compliant.  The VS grammar parser isn't architecturally capable of parsing c++11.

Comment: I know that VS is more often wrong than GCC - but both have errors.  It is also a rather academic exercise - if the code needs to compile with VS, you have to work round its limitations (and anyway, it's confusing as hell for a maintenance programmer too).

Comment: Just as a side note, Clang behaves as GCC.

Comment: @MartinBonner hopefully jack will come back with the relevant section from the spec.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is one case where VS failure to do a 2-phase lookup shows.

A name from a non-template base class will hide the names of the derived class' template parameters. For example:

```
class A
{
public:
   int   T:
};

template<typename T>
class B : A
{
   // here T will mean A::T and not the template parameter
};
```

On the other hand, if the base class is a template, its local names are not known during phase 1 name lookup - so the names will have to bind to what is visible at that point.

```
template<typename X>
class A
{ };

template<>
class A<int>
{
   using T = float;
};

template<typename T>
class B : A<T>
{
   // here a possible A::T is not visible at phase 1
   // so T must mean B::T
};
```

VC++ is known not to perform the name lookup until template instantiation. At that time it knows the real parameters and the real base type, and apparently treats case 2 as if it were case 1.

Comment: Very cool.   I figured it was a VS issue, but had no idea what part of it would cause this type of issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, imho, is the precedence given to the lookup of the type `key_type` and `value_type`.

You chose to use two typenames that are already present in the `std::unordered_map<K,V>` class. Specifically you have

```
using value_type = pair<const K, V>;
```

What happens is that `sizeof(value_type)` refers to the typedef of the `unordered_map` on MSVC and on your custom template argument on Ubuntu. I don't know who's right, I shall take a look at standard but you can see that by trying with

```
  printf("INSIDE(WTF?): sizeof(key_type) = %ld, sizeof(value_type) = %ld\n", sizeof(typename unordered_map<kt, vt>::key_type), sizeof(typename unordered_map<kt, vt>::value_type));
```

in which you force to use the `value_type` from the `unordered_map` you'll get 40 bytes.